# Difference between checking out branch by path from remote and directly by branch name?

Tags: git

I have been struggling to understand the difference between checkout branch by **path from remote** and directly by **branch name**. For instance below is list of branches,

> ```
> remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
> remotes/origin/develop
> remotes/origin/feature/iteration1
> remotes/origin/feature/iteration2
> remotes/origin/master
> ```

Now if I do

> **`git checkout remotes/origin/feature/iteration1`**

then it goes in detached state. Below is the output,

[image]

But now if I do

> **`git checkout feature/iteration1`**

then it points properly to branch, below is the output,

[image]

Please can anyone explain the difference between both checkouts and why it is going to detached state when checking out branch by remote path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first list of branches are **remote-tracking branches**, which are not used as your other local branches by git. They **can't be checked out but only serve as a reference for your remote repository branches**.

When you try to checkout a remote-tracking branch, git follows which commit this branch points to, and checks *this* out, resulting in a detached HEAD state. It allows you to inspect some commit but is not meant to use the branch as a local one, adding/commiting/etc. and is only modified when you fetch from the matching repo.

Answer (score 1):

`HEAD` is actually a reference, which is stored in the file `.git/HEAD` :

```
cat .git/HEAD
```

When you run `git checkout [something]`, `git` updates `HEAD`

1. if `[something]` is the name of a **local** branch, `HEAD` is set to `ref: [branchname]`,
2. in all other cases (raw sha1, tags, remote tracking branches ...), `HEAD` is set to `[sha1 of the target commit]` -- this is the "detached HEAD" state

---

The problem with a "detached HEAD" : it will not be referenced by any name (no tag, no branch ...), and the next time you `git checkout` to jump to some other commit or branch, git may garbage collect this bare commit.

This is why the warning is displayed : to indicate that you should take some action (create a tag, or a branch) if you intend to work on top of this detached `HEAD`.